# Erasing keywords after pressing "Show All" button in MsAccess Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, events, search, keyword-search

Please disregard, just found an answer to this:

In my MsAccess form I currently have:

```
  Keywords window - where I can type text to look up records, by the Client Name,
  Search button - after pressing on it I can see the search results
  Show All button - after pressing on which I see all the records
```

Currently, after pressing **Show All**, whatever I typed in the **Keywords** window stays there. I wish that the keywords would be erased, every time I press **Show All** button

Is it possible to have such result?
If yes, what do I do or - how can I modify my Event Procedure?

Below are my event procedures codes:
btn_Search_Click() - to search by the ceratin keywords
btn_ShowAll_Click() - to show all records

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn_Search_Click()

Dim strsearch As String
Dim strText As String
strText = Me.TxtKeywords.Value
strsearch = "SELECT * from qry_Clients 
where ((ClientName LIKE ""*" & strText & "*"") OR(MedRecNumber LIKE ""*" & 
strText & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch

End Sub

Private Sub btn_ShowAll_Click()

Dim strsearch As String
strsearch = "SELECT * from qry_Clients"
Me.RecordSource = strsearch

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: @WolfgangK - I just modified the original post, to include the codes of my event procedures. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I just found an answer!
In order to be able to clear the textbox after hitting "Show All" button,
I have to add the last string into my

```
Private Sub btn_ShowAll_Click():

Me.TxtKeywords = ""
```